# Photo album for old irregular sized pictures

Tags: archival, printed-album

Can someone please recommend a good photo album for old irregular sized pictures, or tell me what to look for, sizes range from 3.5'x 4.5' (8,9x11,5 cm) and up. I'm not really sure what to look for. The old album had pages with a sticky back so they held photos of any size. But everything now seems to be size for 4'x 6' photos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it hard to believe that an art store or craft store has noting that will do this trick. In the old days we used a scrap book and just pasted pictures using photo corners. You can make these with strips of paper. You can find photo double stick mounting tape. You can find spray adhesives that are labeled photo safe. Now most material warnings are for conventional photo papers. I think that digitally printed photos are immune and you can use ordinary double stick tape and commonly available glues etc.